# moving a rectangle with the d-pad

Tags: python, pygame

im trying to understand the basics of pygame by moving a rectangle using the d-pad on my keyboard but the rectangle isnt moving its staying in its initial position

```
import pygame
import sys

x1=0
y1=0
x2=100
y2=100

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((288,512))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
x = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, x2, y2))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
               y1-=100



pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: you never use y1, how do you expect it to move?

Comment: @Ruli im still confused i added the x1 and y1 to the x variable but i still cant get it to move

Comment: see my answer, you need to move the rectangle when arrow is pressed and update screen to see change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw redraw the entire scene in every frame. This means you have to clear the display, draw the rectangle and update the display in every frame.
Furthermore you to draw the rectangle at the location (x1, y1). When you use [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) the you have to specify the top left position and the width and height of the rectangle:

```py
import pygame
import sys

x1, y1, w1, h1 = 0, 0, 100, 100

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((288,512))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
               y1 += 10

    screen.fill(0)
    x = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (x1, y1, w1, h1))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```